Is this possible for stress whitening to appear in PC+ABS hours to days after stress is applied?
I work for a plastic injection molding business.
We use PC+ABS thermoplastic polymer to produce parts for our customer.
This part was assembled with 4 screws at four corners to a metal part.
After the assembly, we found white spots appearing at the 4 corners where we fasten the screws. We think the white spot is stress whitening from applied stress of the screws.
However, the white spots didn't appear immediately, but took a few hours to days to appear. Is this possible?


Please post a picture if possible.

@Drew Added the photo

You should have the experience to be able to answer this, given this is your work.

Are you using screws with the special plastic-specific thread profile? https://us.screwerk.com/en/shop/grid/stp.html?gad_source=1&gclid=Cj0KCQiArby5BhCDARIsAIJvjIRI1PTndOXXGFyqXCUn6o3rrscN4I1tqhxxbzavjLrIsagza-QArDwaAjbrEALw_wcB

Plastic creeps under constant loads. Whitening under stress is evidence of deformation; slow deformation as in the case of creep will slowly develop the whiteness.

"Is this possible?" Yes, of course it's possible; you can see it happening. I believe your question could be "Is this the likely explanation?"
I suggest that you create a few test pieces with reduced (and measured) torque on the fasteners to determine how much force is causing the stress whitening. Something in the design is allowing initial fastening without discoloration, but then "settling" is causing the part to change geometry.
